# Why Is JanusGraph Or Cassandra Getting A Locking Error?

Tags: locking, cassandra-3.0, docker-container, janusgraph, java-17

## Problem

How do you fix this cascading level of errors when performing sets of `drop().iterate()` iterations?

```bash
[WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Lock write succeeded but took too long: duration PT6.974091S exceeded limit PT0.1S
```

JanusGraph seems to start having errors when writing-with-a-lock takes too long.
This seems like a minor issue that then causes the `Temporary exception during lock write`.
Which snowballs into `Temporary failure in storage backend`.

## Reproduction

### Steps

1. Load [ICIJ Offshore Dataleaks](https://github.com/ICIJ/offshoreleaks-data-packages/blob/eabbabfeaf1983c2b83c11125802fcdeda92d9ac/data/icij-offshoreleaks-44.dump) into JanusGraph

   1. I had this test on [Cassandra [Docker container]](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/cassandra/) but use whatever you're comfortable with

   ```bash
   docker run --name jg-cassandra -d -e CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true -p 9160:9160 -p 9042:9042 -p 7199:7199 -p 7001:7001 -p 7000:7000 cassandra
   ```
2. Run the while-loop of `g.V.limit(10000).drop().iterate()`

   1. This was just around the default limit of memory I had available
   2. Further illustration of code-sample below `Test9.java`
3. Wait awhile (in-terms of processing-load-time length)
4. Results:

   1. Expected: The vertexes to drop to zero-count
   2. Actually: This causes a permanent `TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend`

### Logs

```json
2023-05-11 14:55:54,102 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Lock write succeeded but took too long: duration PT0.126961S exceeded limit PT0.1S
2023-05-11 14:56:01,857 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Lock write succeeded but took too long: duration PT7.346019S exceeded limit PT0.1S
2023-05-11 14:56:14,245 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Temporary exception during lock write
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend 

        ...

    at Test9.commitAndOpenJanusgraph(Test9.java:24) [test-classes/:?]
    at Test9.main(Test9.java:18) [test-classes/:?]
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT12S

    ...

2023-05-11 14:56:18,932 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.pool-5-thread-1] ::    Could not read messages for timestamp [2023-05-11T19:55:54.351076Z] (this read will be retried)
org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: Could not execute operation due to backend exception

    ...

Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Could not successfully complete backend operation due to repeated temporary exceptions after PT4S

    ...

Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend

    ...

Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT12S
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.lambda$scheduleTimeout$1(CqlRequestHandler.java:207) ~[java-driver-core-4.15.0.jar:?]

        ...

2023-05-11 14:56:21,228 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Lock write succeeded but took too long: duration PT6.974091S exceeded limit PT0.1S
2023-05-11 14:56:21,922 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Lock write succeeded but took too long: duration PT0.223427S exceeded limit PT0.1S
2023-05-11 14:56:22,235 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Lock write succeeded but took too long: duration PT0.312938S exceeded limit PT0.1S
2023-05-11 14:56:22,564 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Lock write succeeded but took too long: duration PT0.327949S exceeded limit PT0.1S
2023-05-11 14:56:22,778 [ERROR] [o.j.g.d.StandardJanusGraph.main] ::     Could not commit transaction [1] due to exception
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.TemporaryLockingException: Temporary locking failure
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.locking.AbstractLocker.writeLock(AbstractLocker.java:306) ~[janusgraph-core-1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094.jar:?]
    ... 

2023-05-11 14:56:42,917 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.c.ControlConnection.JanusGraph Session-admin-1] ::   [JanusGraph Session] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042, hostId=b1f215f0-cfa1-48a0-82fe-3c7373fe71f3, hashCode=7e355f55), trying next node (DriverTimeoutException: [JanusGraph Session|control|id: 0x3f0372a4, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:59030 - R:localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (STARTUP {CQL_VERSION=3.0.0, DRIVER_NAME=DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R), DRIVER_VERSION=4.15.0, CLIENT_ID=441714d5-66ad-48f3-b6cc-b15f4adf72dd}): timed out after 5000 ms)
2023-05-11 14:56:48,828 [WARN] [o.j.d.l.c.ConsistentKeyLocker.main] ::   Temporary storage exception while deleting lock
org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend

    ...

2023-05-11 14:56:49,806 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.c.ControlConnection.JanusGraph Session-admin-1] ::   [JanusGraph Session] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042, hostId=b1f215f0-cfa1-48a0-82fe-3c7373fe71f3, hashCode=7e355f55), trying next node (DriverTimeoutException: [JanusGraph Session|control|id: 0xd8e06136, L:/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:59035 - R:localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (STARTUP {CQL_VERSION=3.0.0, DRIVER_NAME=DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R), DRIVER_VERSION=4.15.0, CLIENT_ID=441714d5-66ad-48f3-b6cc-b15f4adf72dd}): timed out after 5000 ms)
```

### Code

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphVertex;

public class Test9 {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        GraphTraversalSource g = janusGraph.traversal();
        janusGraph.tx().rollback();
        commitAndOpenJanusgraph(janusGraph);
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
        while (g.V().count().next()>0)
            g.V().limit(10000).drop().iterate();
        commitAndOpenJanusgraph(janusGraph);
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
        janusGraph.close();
    }

    private static void commitAndOpenJanusgraph(JanusGraph janusGraph) {
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.tx().open();
    }
}
```

### Resources

1. [Maven 3.8.1](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
2. [Java 11.0.19 (corretto-11)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/downloads-list.html)
3. [JanusGraph 1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc2)
4. [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10%20)
5. [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra)
6. [Cassandra:latest [container]](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/cassandra/)
7. [ICIJ Offshore Dataleaks](https://github.com/ICIJ/offshoreleaks-data-packages/blob/eabbabfeaf1983c2b83c11125802fcdeda92d9ac/data/icij-offshoreleaks-44.dump)